# SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near ":OT"

Tags: sql, hana

I tested the code in the document about Hana, but it got an error. I don't know how to fix it. Hope you help.
This is link: https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US/36f718be73e745ceae0530aa80850ce3.html

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_SUM(IN IT TAB, OUT OT TAB) AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE IDX INT = 0;
 DECLARE K VARCHAR(20) = '';
 DECLARE VSUM INT = 0;

 IF IS_EMPTY(:IT) THEN
 RETURN;
 END IF;

 OT = SELECT * FROM :IT ORDER BY K;
 WHILE :OT.K[IDX + 1] IS NOT NULL DO
 IDX = IDX + 1;
 IF :OT.K[IDX] <> K THEN
 IF K <> '' THEN
 :OT.INSERT(('Sum ' || K, VSUM), IDX);
 IDX = IDX + 1;
 END IF;
 :OT.INSERT(('Section ' || :OT.K[IDX], 0), IDX);
 IDX = IDX + 1;
 K = :OT.K[IDX];
 VSUM = 0;
 END IF;
 VSUM = VSUM + :OT.V[IDX];
 END WHILE;
 :OT.INSERT(('Sum ' || K, VSUM), IDX + 1);
END
CALL ADD_SUM(TAB, ?);
```

This is an error:
`Could not execute 'CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_SUM(IN IT TAB, OUT OT TAB) AS BEGIN DECLARE IDX INT = 0; DECLARE K VARCHAR(20) ...' SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near ":OT": line 16 col 2 (at pos 322)`

Comment: What is the version of your HANA DB? Also please, do not truncate the error text, paste it as is. There's `line 16 col 9 (at pos 354)` after the colon which immediately gives you the place of wrong syntax and can easily be checked in documentation.

Comment: @astentx I'm use version 2.3.42

Comment: @astentx I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s generally a good idea to check whether the referenced documentation is the right one for the HANA version in use. HANA 2 has many more and extended features than HANA 1.
The `.insert` syntax for table variables as shown in the example code is one of those added features in HANA 2.
The documentation also has a section “what’s new” that covers the changes between the different product versions.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for helping me over and over again.